# For $e:=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ prove $e^x = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$

Tags: exponential-function

I couldn't find this exact question, apologize if it's a duplicate.

I would like to show based only on the above definition of e, that this equality for $e^x$ holds, without going through showing it's a bijective function, has an inverse function ln, finding it's derivative and finding it's taylor series.
I've tried to play with it, but except for x=-1 (with a proof that doesn't seem to be possible to generalize), I had no progress.

Is their a straightforward proof for that? Or does one has to go through the whole process mentioned above?

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$, if it (evidently) isn't what you're trying to prove?

Comment: Or are you only trying to show it for integer values of $x$?

Comment: It's possible to do it without the method you describe above, say by showing that if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then you can prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n/n!$ converges to $\lim (1+x/n)^n$. This is done or sketched, if I recall correctly, in Baby Rudin in the sequences/series chapter, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extending the Limit Over the Integers to the Limit Over the Reals**

For $\alpha\ge1$,
$$
\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1}\right)^{\large\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}}_{\color{#C00000}{\left(1+\frac{\large1}{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1}\right)^{-1}}\color{#00A000}{\left(1+\frac{\large1}{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1}\right)^{\large\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1}}}
\le\left(1+\frac1\alpha\vphantom{\frac1{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}}\right)^{\large\alpha}
\le\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}\right)^{\large\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1}}_{\color{#C00000}{\left(1+\frac{\large1}{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}\right)}\color{#00A000}{\left(1+\frac{\large1}{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}}}\tag{1}
$$
where the red terms tend to $1$ and the green terms tend to $e$ by the standard limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e\tag{2}
$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $(1)$ and the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) says that
$$
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1\alpha\right)^{\large\alpha}=e\tag{3}
$$
where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $(3)$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1\alpha\right)^{\large-\alpha}
&=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{\alpha-1}\right)^{\large\alpha}\\
&=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{\alpha-1}\right)^{\large\alpha-1}\left(1+\frac1{\alpha-1}\right)\\[9pt]
&=e\cdot1\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(3)$ and $(4)$ give
$$
\lim_{|\alpha|\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1\alpha\right)^{\large\alpha}=e\tag{5}
$$

---

**Applying $\boldsymbol{(5)}$ to the Question**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{\large\frac nx\cdot x}\\[9pt]
&=e^x\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here, by substitution...

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{x}}\right)^n = \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{xm} = \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m\right)^x = e^x$$

This will only work for positive x, but if you've already got it for -1, you should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Oh, no! The OP only knows the limit of the *sequence*, you're computing the limit over the reals, which is a different matter.